# Order by list of values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I am working on social media type application in which companies will upload posts from admin side and all the users can see the posts on user side. Now I have added one option in user settings where user can set which company's posts they want to see on top, and I am storing the list of company ids and user id in a `preference` table, Now while fetching posts I want to order by posts based on the company ids I have stored for that particular user.

After searching I found this [example](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/01/15/oracle-sql-order-by-list-of-values/):

```
select WorkerName, WorkerJob
from Worker
order by decode(WorkerJob,
            'Fisherman',1,
            'Doctor',2,
            'Policeman',3,
            'Nurse', 4) asc;
```

But in this example they have set hardcoded values in order by decode but I want to do it dynamically using list of company ids I have stored in `preference` table.
How can I achieve dynamic decode ordering?

Comment: Redesigning the table structures would make more sense. Hold integer data for WorkerJob  instead of strings, and connect those integer values through adding foreign key constraint referencing primary key column of a parent look-up table(e.g.`preferences` as stated in the answers) populated with those  values such as `1,'Fisherman', 2,'Doctor'...` .

Answer (score 0):

Use `PREFERENCE` table in `ORDER BY` as:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM preference
  3  ORDER BY sort_id;

   SORT_ID JOB
---------- ---------
         1 PRESIDENT
         2 MANAGER
         3 ANALYST
         4 SALESMAN
         5 CLERK

SQL>   SELECT e.ename, e.job
  2      FROM emp e
  3  ORDER BY (SELECT p.sort_id
  4              FROM preference p
  5             WHERE p.job = e.job);

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
KING       PRESIDENT
CLARK      MANAGER
BLAKE      MANAGER
JONES      MANAGER
FORD       ANALYST
SCOTT      ANALYST
WARD       SALESMAN
MARTIN     SALESMAN
ALLEN      SALESMAN
TURNER     SALESMAN
JAMES      CLERK
ADAMS      CLERK
MILLER     CLERK
SMITH      CLERK

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables. (Do a `LEFT JOIN` just in case a worker has an unknown/unlisted job.)

```
select w.WorkerName, w.WorkerJob
from Worker w
left join preferences p on w.WorkerJob = p.WorkerJob
order by p.sort_order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preference` table in outer join and use the `sort_order` as follows:

```
select w.WorkerName, w.WorkerJob
from Worker w left join preference p
on w.WorkerJob = p.WorkerJob
order by p.sort_order
```